# GETH - Anything i can do to get Blocks faster/better?

Tags: go-ethereum

Hi had Variance over 200% and dont get a block for over 2 Hours...

Is there anything i can do, to make the Chance higher to get a Block on Geth?

Like i can say he must use 100% RAM or more CPU Threads or anything on my Server?
I see one Site, using other coin but Ethereum Blockchain and running geth, who is saying `info:Running on 100% RAM Disk .`

What is this?

Comment: You mentioned variance; are you referring to mining a block or do you mean syncing with the blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. The block synchronization is heavily affected by three factors

1. Network performance
2. Disk performance
3. Cpu core performance

I tried to do it on my old pc inside a VM so I had my fair share of wait time and couple of restarts.
You can still consider using `metamask` and `Remix` injecting the web3 provider and it will pick up the meta mask address.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten a block in over 2 hours, there's a good chance that `geth` crashed, especially given that it's using all of your RAM. One bad thing about `geth` is that when it crashes, it does so in the least elegant way possible, in that it doesn't notify the user that it crashed. Check if `geth.exe` (Windows) is still running. If it isn't, you'll need to restart it.

Comment: Its running. But how i can made, that geth use 100% of RAM?

Comment: There is no way to reduce the RAM usage of geth. In order for me to sync on my old windows box, I had to periodically restart geth. I set an alert for every time it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen well-connected machines in data centers sync it in as little as five hours. @Kannan is on the right track. I hope this post will be a little more prescriptive.

Disk, Network, and CPU performance matters. More precisely, it's "latency" that makes the big difference. Latency is the lag between request and response.

- Network: No wireless because that adds latency. Plug into the best wired connection you can find.
- Disk: SSD, of course. They are ideal for random nibbles all over the place. If you have battery-backed write cache that is ideal. It's one of the reasons the server-class systems can do it faster.
- CPU: A VM will do it. I get by with 2-4 i7 cores.
- RAM: An Ubuntu VM with 4GB of RAM will be happy running `geth` with `--cache 2048` which will speed things up.
- `--fast`, `--light` mode. Depending on whether you're running `geth` from command-line or from a wallet GUI "out of the box", the mode will either be the default or something you selected. If you're looking for a way to speed things up with a slower hardware system, you may have to select a mode other than the default. Investigate the options. Do you know what mode it's using now?

Patience.

- Don't interrupt it. Matters have improved so it's not the complete setback that it once was but, generally there is a lot going on in the RAM that hasn't been fully worked out and committed to disk. Interrupting the process increases the overall time needed to finish the job.

There's no reason a reasonably decent laptop won't catch up eventually. If conditions are less than ideal (it's always less than ideal), just expect it to